# Golang worker pool causes database corruption

Tags: database, pointers, go, pool, goroutine

I've been creating a simulator-type system within Golang, and I want to store the data from this system using InfluxDB 2.0's Golang client. However, wanted to see if I can enhance the speed of the database write via a goroutine.

Since setting up a goroutine for every point of data would cause InfluxDB2 to become overwhelmed, I decided to implement a worker pool system that would restrict the number of goroutines used. However, while data *was* written to the database through the worker pool, it would always be corrupted, with strange spikes and variations in values that were not present previously (instead of a straight line, it would be wobbly.)

I am doing this via a function named Simulate, which takes in a time value (used for the time series database), a entity struct pointer (containing all data to be simulated), and two separate clients, each of which write a different set of data.

```
maxNumGoroutines := flag.Int("maxNumGoroutines", 10, "Max num of goroutines")
flag.Parse()

concurrentGoroutines := make(chan struct{}, *maxNumGoroutines) // Semaphore 
var wg sync.WaitGroup // Wait for goroutines to finish

timeLength := setTimeLength(inputVar) // Example of setting length of time

simObjects:= &entities.Objects // objects are propagated as *Object, meaning no return value
// Additional entities also exist inside the entities struct

for timeIterator := 0; timeIterator <= timeLength; timeIterator++ { 
    for _, objectID:= range entities.Objects.GetObjectIDs() { // all objects within the simulation
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(entityState *entities.EntityHolder, chosenObj string, timeGo time.Time) { 
            defer wg.Done()
            concurrentGoroutines <- struct{}{} // Set goroutine as busy
            calc.Propagate(entityState.Objects.GetObject(chosenObj), timeGo) // Edit the value at pointer addr

            calc.Metrics(entityState, chosenObj, timeGo, metricDB) // seperate further calcs and write

            PassInflux(entityState.Objects.GetObject(chosenObj), clientDB, timeGo) // send propagated data 
            <-concurrentGoroutines // Free up goroutine
        }(entities, objectID, timeIterator) // pass in as variables, otherwise operating on changing pointers
    }
}
wg.Wait()
log.Println("Simulation complete.")
```

The Metrics() write is non-blocking, meaning it can write asynchronously. However, I [flush](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-go#non-blocking-write-client) the Propagate() data to ensure that data is sent after all objects have been propagated; without this, too many objects are attempted to be written at once (even though the database uses a batch size of 5000 points).

Am I missing something here? Is there a nominal way to set up a worker pool with pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was using the InfluxDB 2 client incorrectly - I should have been passing a write API into the propagate function instead of the entire client. Doing so meant that the write speed sped up dramatically; as such, the goroutine is not required.